# active css on click using javascript and jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Totaly new on javascript !
I'm trying to apply a `:active` class when clicking on ui window. (blur effect), instead of `modal` effect.

My css:

```
.blur:active {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

My html:

```
<!-- popup -->
        <div id="dialog" title="title">
         <h3><center>Text</center></h3>
        </div>
<!-- img -->    
<img class="blur" src="img/IMG_0125.png" alt="" width="100%">
```

The javascript:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/css/jquery-ui.css" />
<!-- <script src="jquery/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script> -->
<script src="jquery/ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                bgiframe: true,
                height: 350,
                width: 400,
                position: 'center',
                show: {
                 effect: "fade",
                 duration: 1000
                },
                hide: {
                 effect: "fade",
                 duration: 400
                }, 
                resizable: false,
                buttons: {
                    'OK': function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
            $('#popup').click(function() {
                $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            });
            /*The code works until here*/
            $('#popup').click(function(){
                $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            });
        });    
    </script>
```

The jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/5g9t5h2d/#

A click on the image works, the image is bluring, but not when the window appear: How to blur the image when the window appear ?

Comment: can u share a link from jsfiddle too ?

Comment: Why do you have both _jquery-ui.js_ and _jquery-ui.min.js_? Remove `<script src="jquery/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: Never used jsfiddle, but I will try !
Ok, `jquery-ui.js` removed ! Thanks I'm learning :)

Comment: You just can't use _:active_ on an image. And assuming you use `addClass('active')` you have a mess. _:active_ isn't a class. It's pseudo-class. Use _.blur.active_ in your css.

Comment: CSS filters can be animated using the `transition` property :)

Comment: here is the link : https://jsfiddle.net/5g9t5h2d/#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution with `.blur.active { }` in the css, and this code:

```
$(function(){
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: false,
                bgiframe: true,
                height: 350,
                width: 400,
                position: 'center',
                show: {
                 effect: "fade",
                 duration: 1000
                },
                hide: {
                 effect: "fade",
                 duration: 400
                }, 
                resizable: false,
                buttons: {
                    'OK': function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        $('.blur').removeClass('active');
                        $(this).addClass('active');
                    }
                }
            });
            $('#popup').click(function() {
                $('#dialog').dialog('open');
            });
            $('#popup').click(function() {
                $('.blur').addClass('active');
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            });
        });
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5g9t5h2d/2/

Thanks all for your help !